# Filter answers after search when clicking on label (include/exclude)

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, user-interface

When I'm searching for a problem I usually keep my search words "wide".
This results in getting a lot of answers (with their tags shown).

It would be very helpful if I can reduce the search results  by clicking the tags of one of those answers and have the ability to filter or exclude answers with this tag.

This would make a user able to quickly rule out all answers tagged with "javascript" or include only answers tagged with "c#" without having to type the tag filter into the searchbox.

This would improve the UX for people who do not know the existing tags by heart or understand the way they are able to filter based on tags with the searchbox.

Answer (score 1):

You are aware that the sidebar of the search results includes a list of related tags that can be selected for further refinement?  I don't think it would be a good idea to click on the tags of specific questions showing in the results to refine results, because that is not what happens when you click a tag on a question you are viewing.

**EDIT:** As it turns out, the sidebar only shows up if you are searching by tags only.

[image]

But, yes, clicking on a tag on the *sidebar* does refine the search.

[image]

Perhaps a better solution, rather than using the tags on the individual questions as refinement, is to have a list of top tags associated with the particular search conducted (based on the results) in the sidebar to click and refine the search results.

[image]

Adding something similar to what you are proposing here might be a good solution.  The only problem I can see with it is being able to actually getting the list of those tags.  I don't know how efficiently that could be done, or if it would appreciably slow down the page.

Comment: This does not REFINE my search, it just replaces it for a simple query  "all questions marked with label x". So if I hit the label "c#" I lose my original query and end up with all questions on C#, not very helpful.

Comment: In the interests of giving you more time for freehand circles, your SE [accounts are currently linked](http://stackexchange.com/users/481685/saluce?tab=accounts) so there's generally not much point in anonymizing screenshots.